# Do I need Universal Express Pass for my 2 year old child?

Tags: universal-studios

I'm planning a family trip to Orlando, and one of my children is under 3 years old, which means she doesn't need a ticket for the Universal parks. According to their [FAQ](https://www.universalorlando.com/web/en/us/faqs/tickets-and-packages):

> **Do I have to purchase a ticket for my baby?** Children 2 years old or younger are allowed to enter the Park for free (no ticket needed).

I'm also getting Universal Express to skip regular lines for the family members that have a ticket. But, what happens in the case of my 2 year old child? Do I need an additional ticketless Universal Express pass for her? (Can't find that info on their site). Thanks!

Comment: I'm not positive of the answer, but keep in mind that many of the attractions covered by the Express Pass, especially those that tend to have the longest waits, have [height requirements](https://www.universalorlando.com/web/en/us/plan-your-visit/hours-information/ride-height-requirements#universal-studios-florida) that many 2-year-olds won't satisfy, though this of course depends on your child's height.

Comment: @ZachLipton thanks for the feedback. Her height is greater than the average. I already checked -- and she could definitely get on a few of those attractions. I want to keep the fam together in those rides as well, but the Universal Studios FAQ has no info on my specific question :(

Comment: If you enter the Express Pass lane and someone asks for the 2 year old's Express Pass, let them know that it's at the gate with their admission ticket. If they insist on it, offer to leave the child at the line entrance while you go on the ride. :D

Answer (score 4):

If they need a ticket, they would also need Express.

However, under 3 is not specifically documented.  There is a thread on another forum where Universal responded with two conflicting answers.

Keep in mind, under 3 will probably only meet the height requirement for the family spinning rides, Caro-Seuss-el, Kang & Kodo's, etc.  If the supervising adult has Express, it's highly plausible the Team Member won't even check.

Comment: Are you sure of the last statement? All references I can find are that <3 years is free.

Comment: @Doc Actually, it does look like the FAQ is wrong.  You can purchase Child tickets for ages 3-9 years.  The FAQ should say "Children under 3..."

Comment: I don't think it's "wrong", just misleading.  "2 Years old or younger" is referring to anyone who has had their 2nd birthday but not their 3rd birthday. Thus someone that is 2 years and 6 months old is "2 years old".